# Python add entire column to csv file, without reading the file content

Tags: python, file, csv

I need to add columns to a csv file using Python. The only way i can think of doing this is reading the whole file, editing each row to add 1 element, and then write again to the file. However i really don't want to do it this way because of the size of the file (over 32000 rows, seems a lot of reading and writing everytime i want to add a column). Even using the csv module i think the principle would be the same, read everything, edit and write again.

to be clear, below is a csv file example.

```
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
```

i want to add a third column so the file would become:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

If i wanted to add an entire row (or line) i could use `open(csvfile, 'a')` and "append" the last row to the file. Is there a similar option to add a column?

Comment: `awk` or `sed` can be used here

Comment: but even in this cases you have to read (and write) the hole file, don't you?

Comment: No it's not possible. I suggest you use pandas instead of csv library to manipulate your data. A bit overkill but more intuitive.

Comment: Bad solution - Loop through each line.Append the new value. Write it either to new file or the same file. Best solution is to use `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an original csv file, say `foo.csv`

```
1,2 
1,2
1,2
1,2
```

Just create another file holding the column to be added, say `bar.csv`

```
3
3
3
3
```

Then, Unix's [`paste`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) command can be called from within python using `os.system` as

```
import os
os.system("paste foo.csv  bar.csv -d ',' > output.csv")
```

This gives the result `output.csv` as

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Comment: I think using paste, inherently implies that the file would be read to be merged into the new file. However i think this is the best answer! Simple and there is no need to do any data manipulation within Python. I accepted but can't upvote due to low reputation.

Comment: `paste` indeed would go through the entire contents of the file, but it is not reading the entire file together in the memory. It goes through it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not possible. Text files files are sequences and if you want to add something in between you have to shift all the remaining content (and therefore you have to read and write it).