# CSV: how to create new column with numpy.where()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a CSV file with several columns and I want to write a code that will read a specific column called *'ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'* and then, create a new column called "Logical" which will be based on numpy.where(). Here is what I got at the moment:

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv("Results.csv")

data = csv_data[['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']]
data = data.to_numpy()

sol = []
for target in data:
    if1 = np.where(data < 0, 1, 0)
    sol.append(if1)

csv_data["Logical"] = [sol].values
csv_data.to_csv ('Results2.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

So, if the value in the column is bigger than 0, it will record "1", otherwise "0". But it does not create a new column with the corresponding value for each row. What is the mistake?

The example of Results.csv:
[image]

Comment: something is not right in your loop: it doesn't actually use the value of `target`

Comment: @AlenaVolkova any possible alternatives ideas?

Comment: What does `Results.csv` look like? Please post a snippet so we can debug your code.

Comment: @ThomasCuisance your loop creates the same thing at every iteration. You should either use the value of `target` in the loop, or get rid of the loop and only do it once. Also `[sol].values` should raise an error, because `[sol]` is a list and doesn't have attribute `values`.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I have uploaded the screen of Results.csv. It is actually a big file with data, I have highlighted the column we work with. The code needs to check if there is a value bigger than 0 in the column and give back 1 or 0 in the new column (as I described in the question). Please, help. The answer given by another user does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1], [1], [0]], columns=['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'])

df['Logical'] = df['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'] > 0
```

This creates a boolean column. If you want it to be integer instead, with 0/1 values, you can use `astype`:

```
df['Logical'] = df['Logical'].astype('int')
```

Output:

```
| ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount | Logical |
| --------------------------------------------- | ------- |
| -1                                            | 0       |
| 1                                             | 1       |
| 0                                             | 0       |
```

Comment: looks good but I am still struggling to integrate it with a CSV file because 'ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount' is already existing column in CSV file and has like 100k+ rows. How to do it with reading csv?

Comment: if memory allows, just read the whole dataframe (like you did in your question originally), append this `Logical` column as I showed, and write the dataframe back to file with `pandas.to_csv`. If the dataframe is too big to load into memory, you can read only the `ARPU...` column from file with `usecols`, write `Logical` column alone to a new file, and then do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358914/python-add-entire-column-to-csv-file-without-reading-the-file-content

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast solution with `np.where()` with some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_csv("Results.csv") # use read_csv here in your case
df = pd.DataFrame([2400, 3495, -3699, -4771, -608, -3971, -4519, -4863, 1756, 3130], columns=['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'])
df['Logical'] = np.where(df['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'] > 0, 1, 0)
```

Result:

|  | ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount | Logical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2400 | 1 |
| 1 | 3495 | 1 |
| 2 | -3699 | 0 |
| 3 | -4771 | 0 |
| 4 | -608 | 0 |
| 5 | -3971 | 0 |
| 6 | -4519 | 0 |
| 7 | -4863 | 0 |
| 8 | 1756 | 1 |
| 9 | 3130 | 1 |